# AMP Sitemap Error in Google Search Console

Tags: xampp, google-search

After I upload the sitemap to Google Search Console, it shows there is an error about AMP, but I don't know how to fix it.
Anyone can advise me on how to fix the problem?

Thank you so much!

[image]